# XAMPP Apache not reading from Folder after switching to port 81

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to access a folder in Xampp via URL.  When I was originally setting up Apache...Port 80 was in use so I switched the port to 81 in the configuration settings on Xampp:

## Listen 12.34.56.78:81

Listen 81
ServerName localhost:81

When I type in localhost it brings me to a random webpage.  When I enter localhost:81 I am brought to the Xampp Dashboard which is usually seen after the above first attempt.  But when I try to access the folder, which exists in the C:xampp/htdocs/contacts, by typing in localhost:81/contacts I get the below error:

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12

My question is how can I configure my settings in order to access these folders/files which exist in htdocs while using Port 81?

Comment: do you have vhost's declared in your apache configs, if yes, did you create one for port 81 ?

Comment: Would the virtual host be located in the httpd-ssl.conf on the Xampp control panel?  If so, that is pointing towards port 433.

Comment: sorry, i know zilch about m$ft and third party bundles, though I'm pretty sure it is possible to configure a vhost with your setup.

Comment: I solved the problem by uninstalling my text editor(sublime Text) and then while reinstalling...check the checkbox which is next to "Add to Explorer Context Menu."  After that everything ran smoothly

Comment: consider answering your own question. The Q is useful, and your answer solves an issue that other SO user may face.